# How to navigate to an exact url string in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a router set up with parameters

```
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: 'article/:id/:title',
        name: 'ArticleContent',
        component: ArticleComponent
    }
])
```

Somewhere else, I am trying to read the href value of links that looks like this

```
href="article/45/titlehere"
```

and use Router navigate method to route to that url without having to break it up to single params. Is there a straight way in Angular2 to do that? like this?

```
_router.navigate("article/34/titlehere")
```

This isn't working, keep getting

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: linkParams.reduce is not a function
```

PS.  is already set correctly to site root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have url as a string you should use [navigateByUrl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html#!#navigateByUrl) method of Router object:

> **navigateByUrl(url: *string*, _skipLocationChange?: *boolean*) : *Promise<any>***
>
> Navigate to a URL. Returns a promise that resolves when navigation is complete. It's preferred to navigate with navigate instead of this method, since URLs are more brittle.
>
> If the given URL begins with a /, router will navigate absolutely. If
> the given URL does not begin with /, the router will navigate relative
> to this component.

Comment: Adding link to documentation for reference (It is not quite easy to reach these files on Angular website)
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html

Comment: @Ayyash, link is broken.

Comment: yup, angular moves quite fast, now its somebody else's chore to find the right link :)